# Dygraph - where is the leftGap option?

Tags: dygraphs

I'm using dygraphs and I seem to have a gap between my graphs. I found an option called rightGap that accounted for some of the gap, but there's still a gap to the left of the gap. I couldn't find an option called leftGap.

Anyone have an idea how to remove this left gap?

[image]

Thanks,
Uri

Comment: It's hard to help without a picture or demo link clarifying what this "gap" is.

Comment: Hi Dan! I've just added a screenshot of a dygraph chart with the leftgap. The "legend" property is set to "never", "labels" are set to null, but the gap at the left is still there. Thanks for the great dygraph library! It is amazingly fast and high performing.